# Unsupported major.minor version Which one to change?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, version, java

I compiled a servlet with `JDK 7`.
I use Tomcat as servlet container. But it uses an old version of `JVM 1.6`.

Now I have an Error of `Unsupported major.minor version`.

Which one do I have to change ?

- the JVM of Tomcat

OR

- the JDK of my mac ? how to change JDK only for the compilation using cmd-line of one file ?

Answer (score 2):

The version of Java for Tomcat to run under should be one that that version of Tomcat supports. Check the docs on it or just use the one you have that is working.

The version you use to compile should be the same version at least to the same major.minor numbers.

You really should just use the same exact version for running Tomcat and all your development and testing and build and unit test runs and such. It just makes everything easier and gets rid of subtle bugs that waste your time.

Comment: If you're using ANT to create your .class files, in addition to using a matching JDK to do the build I'd advise setting the `target` attribute on the `javac` task. That way regardless of the JDK in use you'll always get classes compatible with the JRE you want.

Comment: Similar thing with Maven builds. You need to set the Java version with  `source` and `target` settings for the `maven-compiler-plugin`

Answer (score 1):

Any one of the two approaches would work. Changing tomcat `JAVA_HOME` would be simple because it won't required your code recompilation (assuming Tomcat you have is compatible with Java 6).

You may simply point `JAVA_HOM`E in your tomcat .bat file to Java 6 location on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Recompile with Java 1.6, and the problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

Of those two options, it's probably easier to downgrade your JVM where you run Tomcat (or choose a different one, since Mac OS allows multiple side-by-side JVM installations).

Another option is to re-compile your code with "-target 1.6" which will compile `.class` files that will be runnable by Java 1.6 virtual machines. This is a better solution IMO because then your later builds will be acceptable to 1.6 JVMs as well.